# Decorating a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I have method that takes as a parameter an array of integer numbers, and I would like to use the decorator pattern to validate first if each of the numbers in the array is in a specified range.

I've seen decorator in ruby that extend class or include modules, but this seems a little excesive to me, is there a way to just decorate a method without relaying on a class or module ?

**EDIT**
I have several methods that takes an array as parameter, and need to validate the range of the items. Instead of inline coding the validation in each of this method, I want a decorator for all of this methods, but I was wondering if decorator classes/modules are the only ones that exist in Ruby ?

```
class MyClass
 ..some code here ...
 def method(array)
   ..some code here...
 end
end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "relying on a class or module"? Could you edit your question to include example code?

Comment: I wonder why you want to use the decorator pattern here.  Why not just validate the arguments inline?  Doing so is about three simple lines.

Comment: Is not just in this method really, there are other methods in my software that could use this decorator too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to wrap methods with a validator:

```
class Foo
  def foo(a, b, c)
    p a, b, c
  end

  def bar(a, b)
    p a, b
  end

  validate(:foo, :bar) {|*args, &blk| args.reduce(:+) == 6 } 
end
```

The `Module#validate` method takes a list of method names, and a block with the validation logic for those methods.

```
foo = Foo.new

foo.foo(1, 2, 3)
# 1
# 2
# 3

foo.bar(2, 4)
# 2
# 4

foo.foo(2, 3, 4)
# [2, 3, 4] (Validator::ValidationError)

foo.bar(2, 3)
# [2, 3] (Validator::ValidationError)
```

As you can see, the validator rejected the argument list in the last two calls because they didn't pass the condition in the block.

This is the "magic" which makes it all happen, which isn't actually that magic. We generate a `module` which overrides the methods we want to validate with a version that `raise`s an exception if the validation fails and then simply calls `super`. Then we `prepend` that module to the class/module that we are currently in, i.e. the one that the call to the `validate` method is in. And that's it, basically.

I chose to also be a good Ruby citizen and wrap the whole thing in a Refinement, so you need to say

```
using Validator
```

to actually activate it.

```
module Validator
  class ValidationError < ArgumentError; end

  refine Module do
    def validate(*methods, &validator)
      prepend(Module.new do
        methods.each do |method|
          define_method(method) do |*args, &blk|
            raise ValidationError, args.inspect unless yield *args
            super(*args, &blk)
          end
        end
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote it down top-to-bottom directly inside the answer window on [so], and only then copy&pasted it into Pry, and it worked on the very first try. That's usually a good sign for a clean and simple design :-D

Comment: Upvoted, that said I'm so *happy* refinements never catched up and really hope they never will, not something I would ever use in my code. And yes, I've been to monkey patching, facets library (if anybody even remember that now) alias_method_chain and all that stuff, but time and practice (enterprise mostly) proved it's baaaad design, don't do it kids!

Answer (score 3):

Normally when you're talking about decorators you'd use that in the context of a class, not a single method.

Here's an example of a class you can decorate:

```
class ValidatorSet
  def initialize
    @validators = [ ]
  end

  def <<(validator)
    @validators << validator
  end

  def valid?(list)
    @validators.all? do |v|
      if v.respond_to?(:valid?)
        v.valid?(list)
      else
        list.all?(&v)
      end
    end
  end
end

class IsUnderTen
  def valid?(list)
    list.all? { |n| n < 10 }
  end
end

validator = ValidatorSet.new
validator << IsUnderTen.new
validator << lambda { |n| n > 0 }

validator.valid?([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])
# => true

validator.valid?([ -1 ])
# => false

validator.valid?([ 9, 10, 11, 12 ])
# => false
```

You see this sort of thing used in the ActiveRecord validation chain.